# Magento2 around method in plugin to save extra field data of customer

Tags: magento2.2, plugin, di

I would like to add extra information to the customer. I have added field in admin side form of customer. I have to save that data. How to add plugin around method during save customer.

Comment: Are you referring to save **Customer Attribute** ?

Comment: Yes i have to save custom customer attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Check below answer.

**`Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`:**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save">
    <plugin name="save_fields" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Customer" />    
</type>
```

**`Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/Customer.php`:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesInterface\Config;

class Customer
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_taxCustomer = $taxCustomer;
    }

    public function aroundexecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save $save)
    {
        $post = $save->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        print_r($post); exit;
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.!!

Comment: I don't have to save customer attribute data from frontend. It will be only change by the Admin. So this solution will not work.

Comment: So, You are looking for adminhtml execute around method via plugin ?

Comment: Yes i'm looking for it.

Comment: @Magecode, Check I've updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this observer event to save additional custom attribute value for back-end.

```
  'adminhtml_customer_save_after',
['customer' => $customer, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]);
```

Creates the events.xml file under the etc folder.

```
<event name="adminhtml_customer_save_after">
        <observer name="customerSave" instance="VenderName\ModuleName\Observer\CustomerSaveAfter" />
</event>
```

Creates the observer file,

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class CustomerSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $data = $this->_request->getParams();
        //Write your save logic here
        $customAttribute = $data['custom_attribute'];
        $customer->setCustomAttribute($customAttribute);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give this in brief? what is ['customer' => $customer, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]);

Comment: I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::save()

Comment: I updated my answer.  Please check it.

Comment: I'm getting an error: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::save() must implement interface Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface